# Bootstrap - How to add borders to one column?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, border

I would like to add Borders In the color 'info' to the last column in the table.
Anyone can know how to do it?

Does Bootstrap support this?

I try this:

```
<style>
    .admin td {
        border-left: 1px solid blue;  border-right: 1px solid blue;
    }
    .admin td:last-child {
        border-bottom: 1px solid blue;
    }
</style>
```

end add class admin to td but not works.

Comment: what have you tried? the question is also not clear.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution:

```
<style>
    .admin td:last-child {
        border-left: 1px solid #3498db;
        border-right: 1px solid #3498db;
    }
    .admin tr:last-child td:last-child {
        border-bottom: 1px solid #3498db;
    }
</style>
```

and class="admin" in table.